# go-gorm postgres dialect: managing structs for jsonb insert and find to properly use json tags

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Been doing a lot of searching, and although i can find a bunch of good articles that explain how to work with the pq package directly. I'm at a loss of working in context of go-gorm and the postgresql dialect.

If in checks.go I use the *ChecksMap* it doesn't let me insert but will let me find. If i use *postgres.jsonb* it lets me insert and query, but the found records will be of jsonb.

Gorm uses the struct of the pointer to determine the db table and schema. This is causing headaches when using a generic searchHandler utility which returns a json response from the API. For any non jsonb types gorm works with the proper structs and uses the json tags, but for jsonb since it doesn't have a reference to the jsonb's "struct" it can't use the json tags. This causes the return API json to have capitalized keys.

```
{
   results: {
      id: "123",
      someId: "456",
      results: [
         {
            Description: "foobar"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to handling this sort of thing so the jsonb results column will be of the correct struct and use the lowercased json tags? Am i just trying to do things which shouldn't be done within the context of go-gorm?

**POSTGRESQL DDL**

```sql
CREATE TABLE checks (
   id        text,
   some_id   text,
   results   jsonb
);
```

**checks.go**

```golang
type CheckRules struct {
   Description   string `json:"description"`
}

type ChecksMap   map[string]CheckRules

type Checks struct {
   ID            string           `gorm: "primary_key", json:"id"`
   SomeID        *string          `json:"someId"`
   Results       postgres.jsonb   `json:"results"`                   // <-- this
   // results    ChecksMap        `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"results"` // <-- or this
}

// func (cm *ChecksMap) Value() (driver.Value, error) {...}
// func (cm *ChecksMap) Scan(val interface{}) error {...}
```

**insertChecks.go**

```golang
var resultsVal = getResultsValue() // simplified
resJson, _ := json.Marshal(resultsVal)

checks := Checks{
   SomeID: "123",
   Results: postgres.Jsonb{ RawMessage: json.RawMessage(resJson) }
}

err := db.Create(&checks).Error
// ... some error handling
```

**getChecks.go**

```golang
var checks Checks

err := db.Find(&checks).Error
// ... some error handling
```

**searchHandler.go**

```golang
func SearchHandler(db *gorm.DB, model, results interface{}) func(c echo.Context) error {
   return func(c echo.Context) error {
      err := db.Find(results).Error
      // ... some error handling

      jsnRes, _ := json.Marshal(results) // <-- uppercase "keys"

      return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, struct {
         Results interface{} `json:"results"`
      }{
         Results: string(jsnRes),
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: Try implementing the `driver.Valuer` interface on the *value receiver*, not the pointer. That is, change `func (cm *ChecksMap) Value() ...` to `func (cm ChecksMap) Value() ...`, will insert still fail if you do that? And if it still fails, can you show what the error is, and if there's no error can you show how you've implemented the `Value()` method?

Comment: @mkopriva That worked. You're a godsend, and I'm starting to develop a self-reflection that includes asking dumb questions that have really stupid answers or typos. Learning Go has been a challenge and JUST found info in the gorm docs that hints about this... http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map but goes into no detail. If you write a short answer about implementing driver.valuer, I feel like it is a suitable answer for the question despite my incorrect code. Then I will be able to upvote. Your call though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the custom `ChecksMap` type but implement the `driver.Valuer` interface on its *value receiver*, not the pointer reciever.

So, instead of:

```
func (cm *ChecksMap) Value() (driver.Value, error) { ...
```

You would write this:

```
func (cm ChecksMap) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if cm == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(cm)
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can probably make it work with the pointer implementation but then you'll have to turn the field into a pointer, e.g:

```
type Checks struct {
   ID      string     `gorm: "primary_key", json:"id"`
   SomeID  *string    `json:"someId"`
   Results *ChecksMap `json:"results"`
}
```

*(although I haven't tested this so I'm not 100% sure how gorm will handle this case)*